# Can I fit an img tag's height inside its parent using Tachyons?

Tags: html, css, tachyons-css

I would like to create a banner that features a logo inside it however my image seems to ignore the height of its parent. [Check out this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4u1tr6m/1/) for an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I can get the layout I want by adding `height: 100%` to the img tag however I'd like to use tachyons to do so and there doesn't seem to be a tachyons class for height 100%. Is there another way to fit the img using tachyons or am I forced to create a class with `height: 100%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want `class="h-100"`!

[tachyons.io Heights docs](http://tachyons.io/docs/layout/heights)